# localhost is not responding due to a long running script ie 11 & angular JS 1.x

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11

My application is working fine in all browser IE , Chrome , FF (except ie 11).
When clicking on the parent link , it is loading an async ajax call through webapi ,which takes 18 seconds to load in all browser except ie 11 .

IE 11 is displaying a message on the footer "localhost is not responding due to a long running script" .Also note the application is working fine .Assuming this is some thing specific to IE 11 .

Any idea would be appreciable .

Comment: AJAX call should not stop browser. Try to check if you have some complex calculations or recursion. IE developer tools is a great tool you can use in this browser. Also you can try to inspect the same code in F12 Chrome DevTools, if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `cache : false` in your ajax call. Rest can be dig down further if you can share code snippet.